# How to add data to an element with ActiveState's dom package

Tags: dom, tcl, activestate, activetcl

In TCL, if you use the DOM package (available in the ActiveState distribution) you can create an xml.

```
set xmlDoc [::dom::create]
set root [::dom::document createElement $xmlDoc "trafficStatistics"]

set statElement [::dom::document createElement $root "Tx_Frames"]
::dom::element setAttribute $statElement "type" "numericlist"
::dom::element setAttribute $statElement "displayName" "Tx Frames"

puts [::dom::serialize $xmlDoc -indent true]
```

creating this simple xml:

```
<result>
    <trafficStatistics type="structure">
        <Tx_Frames type="numericlist" displayName="Tx Frames"></Tx_Frames>
    </trafficStatistics>
</result>
```

How can I add some data to the Tx_Frames element?

```
<Tx_Frames type="numericlist" displayName="Tx Frames">some data</Tx_Frames>
```

Note that the dom package is actually a wrapper over libxml2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want the `::dom::document createTextNode` command.  For example:

```
::dom::document createTextNode $statElement "some data"
```

When I add this command to your sample script:

```
set xmlDoc [::dom::create]
set root [::dom::document createElement $xmlDoc "trafficStatistics"]

set statElement [::dom::document createElement $root "Tx_Frames"]
::dom::element setAttribute $statElement "type" "numericlist"
::dom::element setAttribute $statElement "displayName" "Tx Frames"
::dom::document createTextNode $statElement "some data"
```

It produces this XML:

```
<trafficStatistics>
  <Tx_Frames type="numericlist" displayName="Tx Frames">some data</Tx_Frames>
</trafficStatistics>
```

You can find documentation for the dom package here:

http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/tcldom/index.html

Hope that helps,

Eric Melski